# How do you embed italics in a paragraph with React

Tags: html, reactjs, tags

## Question

As mentioned in the title, how do you embed an `<em>` or `<b>` tag in a paragraph in React?

### Example Output

I'd like to start with a default paragraph like so:

`<p>Lorem ipsum</p>`

then end up with something like:

`<p>Lorem i<i>p</i>sum`

### My Current Workaround

I'm currently splitting the paragraph into a list of spans all containing a single character. This seems clunky and uncool... Would appreciate any help; I'm a React newcomer!

Comment: did you find an efficient solution to this?

Comment: Maybe not the perfect solution, but I included my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I used to get a satisfactory result:

```
const DummyComponent = ({highlightIndex}) {
let aStringVariable = "some dummy text";
const eachLetter = aStringVariable.split("");
return (
    <p>
        {eachLetter.map((letter, index) => {
            if (index === highlightIndex){
                return <em key={index}>letter</em>;
            } else {
                return <React.Fragment key={index}>{letter}</React.Fragment>;
        }
    </p>
}
```